# Connector/NET connecting to MSSQL error - access denied for user 'sa'@'localhost' (using password yes)

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-code

I'm making a program in web api, ASP.NET in Visual Studio Code, using a MSSQL database. I'm making a chat application with SignalR and I want to make the connection in my ChatHub file. When I write the connection correctly, I got an error message: `access denied for user 'sa'@'localhost' (using password yes)`

**Here is my ChatHub.cs code**

```
 public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
        {
            MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn;
            string myConnectionString;

            myConnectionString = "server=localhost;uid=sa;" +
                "pwd=123456789;database=DBChatApp";

            try
            {
                conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
                conn.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
                conn.Open();
            }
            catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"user={user}, message={message}");
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have mixed backends. SQL Server? Or MySQL?

Comment: I'm working on Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18 and I have installed the MySQL Server 8.0 and the Connector/NET too. I am studying the programming and the databeses are new for me. I dont know, which client is for what.

Comment: If you're using MSSQL (Microsoft SQL Server) then why are you installing MySQL related tooling? They're completely different DBMS's.

Comment: I had an another program for login and register pages for users, and I'm used this Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18 for database, where I made the connection in appsettings.json with connection string and its worked there, only I have problem when I want to make the connection like i made in the question.

Comment: Because I tried a lots of things what i find on the internet, and I'm a little bit confused with these database

Comment: Or maybe I need to change the question, that how can I make a connection with MSSQL inside the "public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)"?

Comment: If you w ant to connect to MSSQL, you use the classes inside the System.Data.SqlClient namespace. Get rid of anything that references MySQL in your client. MSSQL and MySQL are completely different DBMS's, and you're only going to confuse yourself by mixing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is MS SQL Server then:

```
public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
{
    string myConnectionString = "server=localhost;uid=sa;" +
                "pwd=123456789;database=DBChatApp";
    try
    {
         using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
         {
                conn.Open();
    Console.WriteLine($"user={user}, message={message}");
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
         }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, that was the problem for me, that I used MySqlConnection not SqlConnection, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Your user name or password are wrong, or your MySQL user doesn't have permission to connect from that host.

As per [specifying account names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/account-names.html), user accounts in MySQL look like `'user'@'host'` and consist of a user name and a host name.

It may resolve your problem to try to create a user account with the details you gave above:

```sql
CREATE USER 'sa'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '123456789';
GRANT ALL ON DBChatApp.* TO 'sa'@'localhost';
```

Comment: thank you .. if I'm using MSSQL than where do I need to write this command? Because on MySQL I need to write in 'cmd' in MySQL bin folder where is 'mysql' file

Comment: If you're using MSSQL then this answer is inapplicable, and none of your code will work, because it's a different database server product. You should ask a new question.